# How to Call Onload Function inside table td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hiii Everone,

I want to check the condition while load td tag.SO that i tried to check the condition with the help of onload function.Below is the example but the code which i tried inside onload is not working please any one help me to get out of this problem.Sceneraio is inside td there will be two button if the condition inside check_course is greater than 1 it will show button 1 or else button 2.

PHP Code

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
require "country.php";
$per_email=$_POST['per_email'];
$stream_name=$_POST['specialization_filter'];
$country_filter=$_POST['country_filter'];
$country = new country();
$users = $country->universities($stream_name,$country_filter);

if ( empty($users) ) {
?>
<br/><br/>
   <?php       echo "<span class=\"alert alert-danger\">No universities Available For Your Search Results!!! </span> <br>" ;

}else{

 ?>
<div class="table-responsive" id="filter_universities">
<table class="table no-border">
<thead >
<tr class="row_univ">
<th class="university_sort" id="name_total_sort" status="asc" style="cursor:pointer">University 
<i class="fa fa-caret-down font-grey-salsa"></i>
</th>
<th class="col-md-3">Program</th>
<th class="fee_structure" id="fee_total_sort" status="asc" style="cursor:pointer">Fee 
<i class="fa fa-caret-down font-grey-salsa"></i>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
 $i=0;
  foreach ($users as $user){ 
   $i++;
?>
        <tr class="tr_bgs">
        <td class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images/university1.jpg" class="img-circle" width="62px" height="62px" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <h5 class="bold fees">
        <a target="_blank" class="university_class" mode="ambitious" cid="292"><?php echo $user['university']?> </a>
        </h5>
        <span class="font-grey-lite"><?php echo $user['country']?> </span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <h5 class="bold fees">  <?php echo $user['course']?> </h5>
        <span class="font-grey-lite"> <?php echo $user['stream_name']?> </span>
        </td>
        <td>
        <h5 class="bold fees"><?php echo $user['fees']?> </h5>
        <span class="font-grey-lite">Per Year</span>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" id="course_button" onload="check_course(<?php echo $user['id']?>);">

 <div id="added_course<?php echo $user['id']?>"><br/><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="delete_course_list(<?php echo $user['id']?>);">
 <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Course Added</button></div>

 <div id="add_course<?php echo $user['id']?>">              
 <br/><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
 onClick="save_course_list(<?php echo $user['id']?>);">
 <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Add to My Course</button></div>
</td>
</tr>   
<tr class="row_univ tr_bgs">
<td colspan="6">
<table class="table no-border no-margin text-grey">
<tbody>
<tr class="tr_bgs">

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>  
<?php
 } 
          }  ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Script

```
function check_course(variable)
  {
    var course_id=str;
    var per_email= '<?php echo $per_email; ?>' ;
    var datas="&course_id="+course_id+"&per_email="+per_email;
    alert(datas);
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/country/check_course.php',
    data:datas
    }).done(function( data ) 
    {
      alert(data);
      if(data>0)
      {
          $('#added_course'+str).show();
          $('#add_course'+str).hide(); 
      }
      else
      {
       $('#add_course'+str).show(); 
       $('#added_course'+str).hide();
       }

      });

  }
```

What mistake i did is there any syntax problem with this.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `variable` that you are passing to the method?

Comment: Variable which i passed is user_id that is what i assigned in course_id.

Comment: Did you try to log and debug? what errors are you seeing on console

Comment: No sandeep nothing is displayed as error.

Comment: i tried your idea but not working plz guide

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `onload()` function inside the **body** tag

or with JavaScript

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        // functions
    }

    // or

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // functions
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I will post the whole code so that u can understand why i want to use onload or td alone

Comment: I dont want to load everythng while process foreach i want to check whether it is correct or not..Then what method i can use for this scenario

Comment: s there any other way to check condition when load td tag

Comment: Or you mean **if the tag is ready**. Here is the code:
`$('the tag you want').ready(function() {
 alert('The element is ready.');
});`

Comment: How i can pass variable in this function @thewbmstr

Comment: dynamically i want to check foreach time td loads so i want to pass id while load td tag.How can i do with this ready function

Comment: `<body onload="check_course(<?php echo $user['id']?>)">` the body tag binds the onload() function

Comment: i tried this but onload function is not at all working

Answer (score 0):

you cant use onload function  to table
use following structure

```
 <body onload="check_course(variable);">
 //your table
</body>
```

Comment: instead of calling ajax recessively on page load will slow down your page loading time  instead of that manage value in php needed and merge with current array.

Comment: I tried like this it is showing check_course function is not defined refrence error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution in using custom attributes that I retrieve in the window.onload function. In my page I used the `<tr>` element, but this should work for a `<td>` also.

In the table:

```
<table>
    <tr name="my_row" foo="value1"><td>value1</td></tr>
    <tr name="my_row" foo="value2"><td>value2</td></tr>
</table>
```

In the window.onload function:

```
window.onload = function bar() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByName("my_row")
    for (row in rows) {
        var foo = row.getAttribute("foo")
        if (foo == "value1") {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```